# Firebase overwrite a single document problem

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to overwrite a single document in Kotlin. For create a document user gives a Target Score and Score(“Score” : 0) created automatically then for every single tap to image the number will increase, but the problem is; if the Target Score e.g. 10, when I tap the image score result is going to directly 10(target score) instead of 1.

Here's my code. Thanks!

```
fun pointClicked(view: View) {

    db.collection(auth.currentUser!!.email.toString()).document(documentId!!).collection("tasks").whereEqualTo("taskDocId", taskDocumentId).addSnapshotListener { snapshot, exception ->
        if (exception != null) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,exception.localizedMessage.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } else {

            if (pointTextView.text.toString().toInt() == targetPointTextView.text.toString().toInt()) {
                println("Task completed")

            } else if (pointTextView.text.toString().toInt() < targetPointTextView.text.toString().toInt()) {

                var increasePoint = pointTextView.text.toString().toInt() + 1

                val setPoint = hashMapOf("point" to increasePoint)

                db.collection(auth.currentUser!!.email.toString()).document(documentId!!).collection("tasks").document(taskDocumentId!!).set(setPoint, SetOptions.merge())
                println("Task is not completed")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: When I tap to imageView once point muss increase +1, E.g. Point value is 0 ("point" : 0), when I tap the imageView once, Point value muss be 1("point" : 1). But it's not increasing +1, point is increasing until value gets equal with targetPoint values.

Here is new codes:

```
fun pointClicked(view: View) {


    db.collection(auth.currentUser!!.email.toString()).document(documentId!!).collection("tasks").whereEqualTo("taskDocId", taskDocumentId).addSnapshotListener { snapshot, exception ->
        if (exception != null) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,exception.localizedMessage.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } else {
            if (snapshot != null) {
                if (!snapshot.isEmpty) {

                    val documents = snapshot.documents
                    for (document in documents) {
                        val point = document.get("point") as Long
                        val targetPoint = document.get("targetPoint") as Long

                        pointTextView.text = point.toString()
                        targetPointTextView.text = targetPoint.toString()

                        if (pointTextView.text.toString().toInt() == targetPointTextView.text.toString().toInt()) {
                            println("Task completed")

                        } else if (pointTextView.text.toString().toInt() < targetPointTextView.text.toString().toInt()) {

                            var increasePoint = pointTextView.text.toString().toInt() + 1

                            val setPoint = hashMapOf("point" to increasePoint)

                            db.collection(auth.currentUser!!.email.toString()).document(documentId!!).collection("tasks").document(taskDocumentId!!).set(setPoint, SetOptions.merge())
                            println("Task is not completed")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clear your point properly it's not understandable and provide database snapshot or structure

Comment: Please try to explain one more time, as it is quite difficult to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Edited with database snapshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is causing a loop (see inline comments):

```
db.collection(auth.currentUser!!.email.toString()).document(documentId!!).collection("tasks").whereEqualTo("taskDocId", taskDocumentId).addSnapshotListener { snapshot, exception ->

        // 
        // CODE HERE WILL RUN EVERY TIME the "tasks" document is updated
        //

        if (exception != null) {
          // ...
        } else {
            if (snapshot != null) {
                if (!snapshot.isEmpty) {

                    val documents = snapshot.documents
                    for (document in documents) {
                        // ...

                        if (...) {
                            // ...

                        } else if (...) {

                            var increasePoint = pointTextView.text.toString().toInt() + 1

                            val setPoint = hashMapOf("point" to increasePoint)

                            //
                            // THIS CODE UPDATES THE SAME DOCUMENT, CAUSING THE SNAPSHOT LISTENER
                            // TO FIRE AGAIN
                            // 

                            db.collection(auth.currentUser!!.email.toString()).document(documentId!!).collection("tasks").document(taskDocumentId!!).set(setPoint, SetOptions.merge())
                            println("Task is not completed")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You're updating a document inside its own change listener.  This causes the change listener to fire again, causing another update.  This repeats until you get to the limit condition, in this case score=10.

It's not exactly clear why you have done this, but I would suggest separating the listener and the score updating part of your code.